# Cannot get toggle function (JavaScript to work)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a simple toggle button using JavaScript, not jQuery, to translate the element back and forth. I did my best a newbie (for JavaScript) but cannot figure it out. The main idea is that the side menu should show from the side when clicked on the button and should hide back to the same place when it is clicked again.
Please help.

```js
function toggleNavBar() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("sideNav"),
    button = document.getElementById("checkButton"),
    check = "hidden";
  if (check == "hidden") {
    nav.style.transform = "translate(0px)";
    check = "shown";
  } else if (check == "shown") {
    nav.style.transform = "translate(-290px)";
    check = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
#sideNav {
  background-color: #96e6b3;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-290px);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(-290px);
  */
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Junction, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  margin-top: 24%;
}
nav ul li {
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-top: 4.7%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: #34cf6d;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Check</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleCheck.css">

  <style>
    <!--very specific small CSS for this document--> #toggler {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #toggler:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="o-content">
      <div class="o-container">
        <div class="o-grid">
          <button id="checkButton" class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx" onclick="toggleNavBar()">
            <span>toggle menu</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sideNav">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="indexCheck.htm">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="items.htm">Items</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="XML.htm">XML</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!--side Nav-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `check = "hidden";
  if (check == "hidden")` will **always** be `true`

Comment: Take a read about [variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description).

Comment: I know there was some problem with that. But thank you so much for pointing it. And can you suggest a fix, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only declare your `check` variable once:

```
var check = "hidden";

function toggleNavBar() {
    var nav = document.getElementById("sideNav"),
        button = document.getElementById("checkButton");
    if (check == "hidden") {
        nav.style.transform = "translate(0px)";
        check = "shown";
    } else if (check == "shown") {
        nav.style.transform = "translate(-290px)";
        check = "hidden";
    }
}
```

A few optimizations (assuming this is done *after* document is ready):

```
var toggleNavBar = (function() {
    var check = "hidden";
    var nav = document.getElementById("sideNav");
    var button = document.getElementById("checkButton");
    return function() {
        if (check == "hidden") {
            nav.style.transform = "translate(0px)";
            check = "shown";
        } else {
            nav.style.transform = "translate(-290px)";
            check = "hidden";
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to `else if` over `else`? Not all code paths do things

Comment: @arthrax Glad it worked.  If it fixed your problem for you, please mark an answer as accepted so other users know which solution you used.

Comment: DOM references can also be moved outside of function

Comment: @Tushar Only if they are static, otherwise you don't. It's also a good idea to avoid unnecessary global variables.

Comment: Added an optimized version with most of those suggestions.

Comment: @TbWill4321 Not _optimized_ IMO. Create a class `.trans { transform: translate(0px); }` and in handler toggle it, `nav.classList.toggle('transform');`

Comment: @Tushar, do you mean `nav.classList.toggle('trans');`?